# import model in next js 13 middleware

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware

I'm using Next.js 13 and I have a User model in my application.

for user authentication, I should import my User model in middleware.js file.

when I import a model in middleware, this error happen.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
```

how can I solve it?